# Determine the value of $a$ and $b$ such that $(ax+3)/(bx+5)$ has $f (-2)= 1$ and $f '(-1) = 1/4$?

Tags: calculus

I tried using the quotient rule but I honestly have no clue how to do this!

Can someone try to help?

$f(x)=\dfrac{ax+3}{bx+5}$.

Determine $a$ and $b$ such that $f(-2)=1$ and $f'(-1)=\frac14$.

Comment: (ax+3)/(bx+5) sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Write the function $f$ has $g/h$ with $g(x) = ax + 3$ and $h(x) = bx + 5$. Then

$$g'(-1) = a \text{ and } h'(-1) = b$$

Hence by the quotient rule, we see that

$$f'(-1) = \frac{h(-1) g'(-1) - h'(-1) g(-1)}{h(-1)^2} = \frac{(5 - b)a - b(3 - a)}{(5 - b)^2} = \frac{5a - 3b}{(5 - b)^2}$$

Now using the fact that $4f'(-1) = 1$, we see that

$$20a - 12b = (5 - b)^2$$

On the other hand, using the fact that $f(-2) = 1$, we have another equation

$$3 - 2a = 5 - 2b$$

Use these equations to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, thank you very much.

Comment: How did you get 20a - 12b ?

Comment: @Jesse $4 (5a - 3b) = 20a-12b$.

Comment: but why isn't it just 20a-12b = 1? why does 20a-12b = (5-b)^2?

Comment: @Jesse Rearrange the expression $4f'(-1) = 1$; I just moved the denominator $(5 - b)^2$ to the right side.

Comment: oh wait never mind!

Comment: im so sorry but how did you get the other equation?

Comment: @Jesse Just rearrange the statement $f(-2) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that despite the missing required parentheses, $f(x)$ is supposed to be

$$f(x)=\frac{ax+3}{bx+5}\;.$$

You do indeed want the quotient rule to differentiate $f$:

$$\begin{align*}
f\,'(x)&=\frac{(bx+5)(ax+3)'-(ax+3)(bx+5)'}{(bx+5)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{a(bx+5)-b(ax+3)}{(bx+5)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{abx+5a-abx-3b}{(bx+5)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{5a-3b}{(bx+5)^2}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now you want $$1=f(-2)=\frac{-2a+3}{-2b+5}=\frac{3-2a}{5-2b}\tag{1}$$ and $$\frac14=f\,'(-1)=\frac{5a-3b}{(-b+5)^2}=\frac{5a-3b}{(5-b)^2}\;.\tag{2}$$

Multiply $(1)$ through by $5-2b$ to get $5-2b=3-2a$, and multiply $(2)$ through by $4(5-b)^2$ to get $(5-b)^2=4(5a-3b)$. Each of these can easily be solved for $a$ in terms of $b$:

$$\begin{align*}
a&=b-1\;,\text{ and}\\
a&=\frac1{20}\left(b^2+2b+25\right)\;.
\end{align*}\tag{3}$$

Now equate the righthand sides of $(3)$ to get a quadratic in $b$; you can solve that, and then use $b$ to find $a$.

Comment: Oh boy! This rocks! Thanks!

Comment: Is it the same if I got -a-1 = -b?

Comment: @Jesse: You’re welcome. Yes, $-a-1=-b$ becomes $a+1=b$ when you multiply both sides by $-1$, and that in turn becomes $a=b-1$ when you subtract $1$ from both sides.

Comment: I can't quite seem to get line (3) because I got 5a-3b = 1/4(b^2 + 2b + 25)

Comment: @Jesse: Now multiply through by $4$ to get $$4(5a-3b)=b^2+2b+25\;,$$ multiply out the lefthand side to get $20a-12b$, and solve for $a$.

Comment: but how would we solve this is there are no real roots in the quadratic equation?